# a day of, or the day of?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I wrote this thing;

> "I woke up as any other usual day, but my spirit was high. After a
>   long period of non-stop, vigorous working, I finally could relax, as
>   it was *a/the* day of rest."

I strongly feel that "the" can be used in that sentence, as it is a reason, a very definite reason that is, for my being able to relax. Therefore, even though my readers will not have any information prior to reading this,  I think "the" should be used.

Am I right? I always have difficulty knowing which article to use. If I am wrong, please tell me the difference between the nuances of those uses.

Edit:

I think that implied noun is "the day of rest that finally allowed me to relax", which I think is a referent unique enough to be used with a definite article.

Like this: I like to write stuff on the book when I annotate a book. It is sure that I am not referring to a specific book. But I used "the" instead of "a", because it refers to a book that I am annotating in a hypothetical situation. It is implied, which I think makes it definite.

Please correct my analogy if I am wrong.

Comment: Using *the* would have to imply a specific day. For example, if you don't ever do work on Sundays, you could call it "*the* day of rest". Otherwise, it needs to be *a*. Almost always, *a* is used in this kind of phrase, since there are so many days.

Comment: @user3169 But isn't it specific that is is the day (which is of rest) that allowed me to relax, not just a day of relax?

Comment: That is only specific to the *kind* of day. Surely you will rest on other days.

Comment: @user3169 Does "the" imply there is only one day of rest that I can get out of all the days? Like the day of her death or alike?

Comment: Only if it is in the context. You said "as it is a reason, a very definite reason", but did not say specifically which date it was.

Comment: @user3169 Yes. I thought that implied noun is "the day of rest that finally allowed me to relax", which I think is a referent unique enough to be used with a definite article?

Comment: @user3169 Like this: I like to write stuff on _the_ book when I annotate a book. It is sure that I am not referring to a specific book. But I used "the" instead of "a", because it refers to a book that I am annotating in a hypothetical situation. It is implied, which I think makes it definite.

Comment: @user3169 Am I wrong about the analogy above?

Comment: How can you write *in* a book that is not a specific one? In any case, I was hoping some other users might chime in on this.

Comment: @user3169 It is specific that it is _the_ book I am writing in in a hypothetical situation. It can be any book, as long as I am writing into it, but it is definite because it is the one that I write into in a hypothetical situation.

Comment: @user3169 Here is the discussion in which that analogy was discussed;http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43837/discussion-between-whitedevil-and-alan-carmack

Answer (score 1):

Whether to use "a" or "the" depends on what you are trying to say.
If you habitually rest on a particular day, then you would use

> the day of rest

and refers to a particular day one does not work and can be understood to be *naming* that day as a "day of rest"

> a day of rest

refers to a day, in general, when one does not work

> "**A** day of rest" is not necessarily "**the** day of rest", but
>   "**the** day of rest" is definitely "**a** day of rest".

In your book analogy sentence sounds a bit awkward

> I like to write stuff on **the** book when I annotate **a** book.

You are actually using the shorthand of

> I like to write stuff on **the** book *(that I am annotating)* when I annotate **a** book.

and the meaning is

> I like to write stuff on **the** *(cover of the)* book that I am **annotating**.

Using "on" implies you are writing on the outside of the book in your context. If you were writing regarding the contents of the book, you might use "about"

> I like to write *about* the book *(I am annotating)* on its cover.

Comment: Thank you. I meant to say "I like to write stuff in the book when I annotate a book." I meant it to be the shorthand of this; "I like to write stuff in the book (that I am annotating in a hypothetical situation, or, in other words, any book that I might be annotating at any give time, not a specific book, but definite that it can only be the book that I am annotating) when I annotate a book". Does it make sense?

Comment: Or is my analogy wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence provides details about why you can finally relax, not about day of rest.

As such, it is most natural to use *a day of rest*, as you are not talking about any day of rest in particular. You would use *the day of rest* if (a) you assume your hearer can identify which day of rest it is; or (b) if you want to make *day of rest* the topic of the discourse (and so you will go on to talk about *the day of rest*).

You have to more tightly link these reasons/details to *day of rest* in order to make it definite. One way to do this is by using *the day of rest* to head a relative clause that further defines it. Consider any of the following:

> "I woke up as any other usual day, but my spirit was high. After a long period of non-stop, vigorous working, I finally could relax, as it was the day of rest I had long been looking forward to."

or

> "I woke up as any other usual day, but my spirit was high. After a long period of non-stop, vigorous working, I finally could relax, as it was the day of rest I deserved after working so hard."

Now, the hearer can identify *which day* of rest you are talking about. And only now are you being "very definite" about which day of rest you are talking about.

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question; is it okay to use "a day" with those definite days involving "I had been looking forward to" and "I deserved working so hard"?

Comment: Well, one thing the relative clause does is to identify which day you're talking about,  so *the* is natural there. The indefinite article wouldn't work so well there, so poorly that it would be unusual and unidiomatic  to find it there. I mean an English speaker can use the definite or indefinite article whenever he wants  but the usage may or may not be the customary, expected or idiomatic usage. Here, it is not the expected usage. There could be a context where it might work  so I rarely say never or ever regarding certain usages. @whitedevil

Comment: I found this; "This is an important and a happy day, _a day of achievement_ that we will always remember with optimism and hope." How is it different from the ones up there? I'm quite confused.

Comment: Remember, the indefinite article can make a specific reference (*I married a woman from Japan*). So the sentence you now ask about is talking about a specific day, but it is not saying that it is the only day that we will remember with optimism and hope. There could be, and probably are, several such days and *this day* is just one of them.

Comment: So with this sentence, "I finally could relax, as it was the day of rest I deserved after working so hard", if there are many such days that I deserve, can I use "a day of rest"?

Comment: @whitedevil Yes!

Comment: I thought it was going to sound unidiomatic! Because you said it is an unexpected usage.  I mistyped several times.

Comment: Is it the only exception?

Comment: @whitedevil these things can get pretty subtle. My advice for you is just get exposed to more and more natural, native English (movies, radio, TV, speaking with native speakers, books on your level). The more you do  the more the various uses of the definite vs indefinite article you will encounter in a realistic meaningful context. Soon, you will pick up on these uses and they could start to become second nature. Asking about sentence after sentence does not seem very productive, speaking long term and also regarding actually communicating in the language.

Comment: Don't be afraid of making mistakes; it's part of the language learning process and a good way to improve (we learn by our mistakes).